# VueJS - custom event doesn't work when I use the $emit

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have the following component code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <div
            @click="runSomeMethod()"
        >
            Click Me
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        runSomeMethod: function() {
            this.$emit('searching');
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

And then I have the following page:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Form @searching="doSearching()" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Form from "./HomeComponents/Form";

export default {
    components: {
        Form
    },
    methods: {
        doSearching: function () {
            alert('Hello');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And when I do the click inside the first component, the event is triggered and I can see it in my  Vue console like that:

[image]

But the method `doSearching` is not executed. Do you see if I am doing something wrong? Do you see any error? Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: I see no problems with the code itself.  Try changing the component name `Form` to something that isn't a real HTML tag.

Comment: @Dan I've tried this solution too but still not working :(

Comment: Something else must be wrong, the code you've shown here is ok:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/8qhsvudy/